# Terraform how to get dynamic route in route table

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

**Terraform how to get dynamic route in route table based on the workspace**

> UAT

```
resource "aws_vpn_gateway" "micorsoft_vpn_gw" { 
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.default.id

  tags = {
    Name = "micorsoft"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "private" { 
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.default.id
  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.default.id
  }
  
  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id     =  aws_vpn_gateway.micorsoft_vpn_gw.id
  }

  tags = merge(map("Name", "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}"), var.tags)
}
```

> DEV

```
resource "aws_route_table" "private" { 
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.default.id
  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.default.id
  }
 
  tags = merge(map("Name", "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}"), var.tags)
}
```

How to achieve this is dynamic way based on workdspace/environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can use [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) for that.

```
resource "aws_route_table" "private" { 
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.default.id

  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.default.id
  }
  
  dynamic "route" {
      for_each = var.env == "DEV" ? toset([]) : toset([1])
      content {
        cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
        gateway_id     =  aws_vpn_gateway.micorsoft_vpn_gw.id
      }      
  }

  tags = merge(map("Name", "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}"), var.tags)
}
```

Basically, when the `var.env` is `DEV`, no second `route` will be created.

Comment: Thanks a lot @marcin. I am implementing, so let me know the outsome