# Using for_each in aws_route_table to create routes to subnets in different availability zones

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to automate as much as possible with terraform. I am using 2 VPCs (1 application, 1 management). In the 1st VPC (app), I use count to determine the number of availability zones (AZs) in a given region & create subnets for each AZ. That part works. In the 2nd VPC (management), I have 1 subnet that needs to talk to these 3 subnets in VPC1. Basically, I want to automate the creation of aws_route_table to have this:

```
VPC2.subnet1 ------> VPC1.subnet1
                |--> VPC1.subnet2
                 --> VPC1.subnet3
```

But with my code, I end up having 3 separate aws_route_table resources:

```
VPC2.subnet1 ------> VPC1.subnet1
VPC2.subnet1 ------> VPC1.subnet2
VPC2.subnet1 ------> VPC1.subnet3
```

Here's my bad code:
Getting all the AZs in the region:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {}
```

Automatically creating subnets in each AZ using count:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "app_public_subnet" {
  count = length(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names)

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  availability_zone = element(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names, count.index)
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet(var.app_vpc_cidr_block, 8, count.index + 1)

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}_app_public_subnet_${count.index + 1}"
  }
}
```

Trying to create aws_route_table resources using for_each, but the code below creates 3 separate aws_route_table instances, instead of 1 instance with the 3 routes inside. I am new to terraform, I am still learning.

```
resource "aws_route_table" "mgmt_rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.mgmt_vpc.id

   for_each = toset(aws_subnet.app_public_subnet[*].cidr_block)
   route {                                                         # Route via VPC peering connection
     cidr_block = each.value
     gateway_id = aws_vpc_peering_connection.mgmt_peer.id
   }

  route {
    cidr_block = var.all_cidr
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.mgmt_igw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}_mgmt_rt"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to use [`dynamic` blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform how to get dynamic route in route table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64334897/terraform-how-to-get-dynamic-route-in-route-table)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but it demonstrates the usage of the `dynamic` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your `for_each` to [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) for `route`. For example:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "mgmt_rt" {

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.mgmt_vpc.id
 
   dynamic "route" {

     for_each = toset(aws_subnet.app_public_subnet[*].cidr_block)

      content {
       # Route via VPC peering connection
         cidr_block = route.value
         gateway_id = aws_vpc_peering_connection.mgmt_peer.id      
      }
   }

  route {
    cidr_block = var.all_cidr
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.mgmt_igw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}_mgmt_rt"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out something new to me - dynamic blocks.

Trying it out, but still having problems - probably I am referencing the wrong 'object' or something. Still need to figure it out.

Comment: I am getting the following error:

"A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it
unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in
its "for_each" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your
configuration to work around this error."

Comment: @nyxx88 There is no each.value in my answer.

Comment: You are ABSOLUTELY right! I did not copy your code (so I can learn), but instead modified my own code & i used each.value in my code. Now I found my mistake & it works! I am sure I will remember this lesson - mistakes are usually the best teachers.

Thank you once again!